# How to set size of a dragging Visual from a Style?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have drag'n'drop support in my application. When I start dragging a certain item, I create the dragging visual from code. The code below works, but I want to set the width and height using the style instead of hardcoding it like below. How?

```
private void OnDragInitialize(object sender, DragInitializeEventArgs args)
{
    args.AllowedEffects = DragDropEffects.All;

    var shape = new MyShape();

    // TODO: How do I let the 'DragShapeStyle' style apply the dimensions?
    var shapeSize = new Size(180, 80);

    var dropInfo = new DiagramDropInfo(shapeSize, SerializeItems(
        new List<IDiagramItem> { shape }));

    args.Data = dropInfo;
    args.DragVisualOffset = new Point(
        args.RelativeStartPoint.X - (shapeSize.Width / 2),
        args.RelativeStartPoint.Y - (shapeSize.Height / 2));

    var dragShape = new DragShape()
    {
        DataContext = new ShapeData()
        {
            Data = new MyData()
        }
    };

    dragShape.SetResourceReference(DragShape.StyleProperty, "DragShapeStyle");

    args.DragVisual = new ContentControl() { Content = dragShape };
}
```

My `DragShapeStyle` style paints a grid, with its size set using properties of `MyData` and some other logic. I want to apply this logic to my dragged Visual.

Comment: your style is based on the item you are dragging?

Comment: No. The style is based on the dynamically created `DragShape`.

Comment: you mean there is only one dragshape style and you want to apply it on each item you are dragging?

Comment: The styling is no problem. The dragged item looks good. The problem is that I currently need to explicitly set the width/height of the `ContentControl`. I would like those properties to be 'inherited' by the width/height of its styled `Content`. Something like `ContentControl.Width = "Bind ActualWidth from Content.Style.Grid"`...